# Question about prcomp() in R. I want my country names on the plot

Tags: r

I am using prcomp() on a dataset, but R said "Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric"

I know all col should be numeric, but the country col is not one of the x- factor. What should I do to let R knows it. I tried deleting the whole country col and then R thinks the number is my y-factor instead of country. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQdVj.png)

I would like to output a plot like this . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjuZs.png) . Instead, this is the best I can do [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSvYZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
dd <- `rownames<-`(within(USArrests, State <- rownames(USArrests)), NULL)
head(dd)
#   Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape      State
# 1   13.2     236       58 21.2    Alabama
# 2   10.0     263       48 44.5     Alaska
# 3    8.1     294       80 31.0    Arizona
# 4    8.8     190       50 19.5   Arkansas
# 5    9.0     276       91 40.6 California
# 6    7.9     204       78 38.7   Colorado

biplot(prcomp(dd))
```

> Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

```
rownames(dd) <- dd$State
dd$State <- NULL
biplot(prcomp(dd, scale. = TRUE))
```

[image]